# IBM Worklight 6.1 - connectAs endUser before authentication

Tags: authentication, adapter, ibm-mobilefirst, end-user

I have a question about the `connectAs="endUser"` option, found in the adapter XML file.

In the design mode I can read

```
   - endUser: The connection to the back end will be created with the user's identity, as authenticated by the authentication realm
```

So my question is: Does it have sense to use the option `connectAs="endUser"` without being authenticated and without defining a security test?

I am having this question, because I used to put the `connectAs="endUser"` in the authentication procedure

```
<procedure name="authenticate" connectAs="endUser"/>
```

Is that wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as you can see in the documentation using connectAs="endUser" is "Only valid if a user realm has been identified in the security tests for this procedure."

Here are some resources you may want to look into:

**procedure element of the adapter XML file**

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.dev.doc%2Fdevref%2Fr__procedure_.html&resultof%3D%2522%2563%256f%256e%256e%2565%2563%2574%2561%2573%2522%2520%2522%2563%256f%256e%256e%2565%2563%2574%2561%2522%2520

**The authentication element of the HTTP adapter**

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.dev.doc%2Fdevref%2Fr_the__authentication__element_o.html&resultof%3D%2522%2563%256f%256e%256e%2565%2563%2574%2561%2573%2522%2520%2522%2563%256f%256e%256e%2565%2563%2574%2561%2522%2520

Can you please provide your scenario to how you would like to use this setting in greater detail